# Macro argument and pgf key interpretation problem

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

In this mmwe, the same test work if used on a parameter of a macto and fails on a pgf key. Any idea why ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\makeatletter

\ifluatex
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp
\let\pdffilemoddate\pdf@filemoddate
\fi

\tikzset{%
    Cote/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
               \draw[>=latex,|<->|] let
    \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
    \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
    in(\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above]{\Cote{\@aspect}};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
        }(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
}

\pgfkeys{tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.store in=\@aspect,
    aspect=o,
} 
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{m
    }{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        true
    \else
        false
    \fi
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Cote{(F)} -- \Cote{F}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[Cote/aspect=F] (0,0) to[Cote] (5,0) ;

\path[Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,2) to[Cote] (5,2) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit** There is a problem with a more complex macro. My mwe was too minimal.

The non minimal exemple is my answer to this question : [How to define at tikz style option to draw a dimension line between to specific points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417617/how-to-define-at-tikz-style-option-to-draw-a-dimension-line-between-to-specific/417736#417736)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\makeatletter

\ifluatex
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp
\let\pdffilemoddate\pdf@filemoddate
\fi

\tikzset{%
    Cote/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
               \draw[>=latex,|<->|] let
    \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
    \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
    in(\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above]{\expandafter\Cote{$\pi$}\expandafter<\@aspect>};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
        }(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
}

\pgfkeys{tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.store in=\@aspect,
    aspect=o,
} 
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{md<>
    }{%
    #1
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#2\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        true
    \else
        false
    \fi
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Cote{$\pi$}<($\pi$)> -- \Cote{$\pi$}<F>

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[Cote/aspect=F] (0,0) to[Cote] (5,0) ;
\path[Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,2) to[Cote] (5,2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure you want `\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp` ?????????

Comment: not surprisingly your document loops forever after that definition.

Comment: Based on egreg's here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132248/test-if-the-first-character-of-a-string-is-a answer, this test worked since a long time if I test a macro parameter. I want to use this test on a pgfkey and it fails. I confess that it is a magic formula for mee ;-)

Comment: your document if used with pdftex never terminates and has to be killed from the operating system. That does not appear to match the behaviour that you are asking about? Are you testing with luatex or xetex rather than pdftex?

Comment: egreg's answer does not suggest `\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp`  (which defines `\pdfstrcmp` to loop indefinitely)

Comment: @Tarass: There is no `\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp` in that linked code. Furthermore, you should say what `\pdf@strcmp` is supposed to be before you use that as a `\let` replacement

Comment: I just test pdflatex and loops indeed, but lualatex works fine... ans produce the document I posted as an image. I never use pdflatex, I didn't know it loops.

Comment: there is a _reason_ that the `pdftexcmds` package uses consistent _new_ names for all the commands it defines. Both your `\let` statements completely break it.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Without the package the compilation fails with lualatex, whit the package it fails with pdflatex. I suppose one have too chose, the one or the other way? I chose lualatex and the package, ifluatex can prevent the misloading of the package. Is it normal that it works with lualatex ? And if yes, why the pgfkey issue ?

Comment: I tried my mwe without the package ans the two line, the compilation works, the test work on macro parameter but not on pgf key.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I add the ifluatex, no more loops, still my question.

Comment: No why choose? Just use the package as intended and use `\pdf@strcmp` and `\pdf@moddate` without  renaming them back on the original names. (but the ifluatex version works)  note there is not really any question in your question. You just say "it fails" without saying what you get or what you expected.

Comment: Are we agree on my correction loading ifluatex? My question in on the failling of the test : it works fine with a macro parameter, and does no give the right answer if I test a pgfkey, what I call `fails`.

Comment: the correction using ifluatex avoids the loop in pdftex but is not really how you are intended to use the pdftexcmds package. There are multiple issues in renaming the aliases defined there to have the same names, you got lucky and in this case the modified code works in pdftex and luatex but in general it will not. So while it is not completely broken with an infinite loop it is not correct.

Comment: please do not describe a problem as "does not give the right answer"  The code you posted _does_ give the right answer, it works as designed and gave the answer I expected.  But you made me guess what answer _you_ expected which is hard to get right without a crystal ball. Luckily I had  a working one today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I guess that you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\makeatletter

\ifluatex
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp
\let\pdffilemoddate\pdf@filemoddate
\fi

\tikzset{%
    Cote/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
               \draw[>=latex,|<->|] let
    \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
    \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
    in(\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above]{\expandafter\Cote\expandafter{\@aspect}};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
        }(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
}

\pgfkeys{tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.store in=\@aspect,
    aspect=o,
} 
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{m
    }{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        true
    \else
        false
    \fi
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Cote{(F)} -- \Cote{F}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[Cote/aspect=F] (0,0) to[Cote] (5,0) ;

\path[Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,2) to[Cote] (5,2) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to test the first token of `@aspect` is `(` rather than test if `@aspect` is `(` (which is always false)

Comment: As a wizard, you guessed what I didn't say ;-)

Comment: I updated my question, because I don't know how adapt your answer to my more complex macro. My mwe was to minimal. I' sorry.

Comment: @Tarass you know it's bad form to change the question after answers posted, especially after they are accepted. (as its's showing as answered basically no one but me is likely to see the new question, if you had asked it as a new question, someone else could tale a turn.

Comment: Next time, I will carefully look if it solves the nmwe before to accept it. Sorry again.

Comment: Thank you your patience and advices. I posted a new question here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417799/pgfkey-and-macro-parameter-pass-the-same-test-differently