# pgfkey and macro parameter pass the same test differently

Tags: pgfkeys

In the next MWE, the test provided on a macro parameter gives the expected answer (it finds if the parameter begins with a `(`), but the same test fails on or ignores the pgfkey it has to test.

This is a minimal example, it is to finish my answer to this question : [How to define at tikz style option to draw a dimension line between to specific points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417617/how-to-define-at-tikz-style-option-to-draw-a-dimension-line-between-to-specific/417736#417736)

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\makeatletter

\ifluatex
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}
\let\pdfstrcmp\pdf@strcmp
\let\pdffilemoddate\pdf@filemoddate
\fi

\tikzset{%
    Cote/.style={to path={\pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
               \draw[>=latex,|<->|] let
    \p1=($(\tikztostart)!2mm!90:(\tikztotarget)$),
    \p2=($(\tikztotarget)!2mm!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
    in(\p1) -- (\p2) node[pos=.5,sloped,above]{%
    \expandafter\Cote\expandafter{\@aspect} -- 
    \expandafter\CoteBis{$\pi$}\expandafter<\@aspect>};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
        }(\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
}

\pgfkeys{tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.store in=\@aspect,
    aspect=o,
} 
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\Cote}{m}{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        true
    \else
        false
    \fi
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\CoteBis}{md<>
    }{%
    #1
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#2\@nil}}{(}=\z@
        true
    \else
        false
    \fi
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb+\Cote+ : \Cote{(F)} -- \Cote{F} : The test gives the expected answers

\verb+\Codetis+ : \CoteBis{$\pi$}<(F)> -- \CoteBis{$\pi$}<F> : The test gives the expected answers

\bigskip

In the \verb+\Cote+ macro, the test gives the expected answers

In the \verb+\CoteBis+ macro, the test gives unexpected answers

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[Cote/aspect=F] (0,0) to[Cote] (5,0) ;
\path[Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,1) to[Cote] (5,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

- `\CoteBis` is never called in the TikZ style `Cote`. I assume the second `\Cote` should be `\CoteBis`.
- `\expandafter` only jumps over *one* token, not a group of tokens. Thus, the line

  ```
  \expandafter\Cote{$\pi$}\expandafter<\@aspect>
  ```

  needs much more calls of `\expandafter` (and probably `\CoteBis` instead of `\Cote`):

  ```
  \expandafter\CoteBis\expandafter{%
    \expandafter$\expandafter\pi\expandafter$\expandafter}%
    \expandafter<\@aspect>
  ```

The result:

[image: Fixed result]

Comment: Sorry, post the wrong code. I made the corrections.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I try to adapt your solution to my code here, but it still not working. Could you take a look, please ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417617/how-to-define-at-tikz-style-option-to-draw-a-dimension-line-between-to-specific/417736#417736

Comment: Thanks. (Sorry, can't upvote again for the fix.) I'll try to remember about the typos - just some people don't like anybody to touch their answers, even for typos. (Personally, I'm happy if somebody does this for me!)